# Why doesn't yaw angle return to its 0 state after rotations?

Tags: imu, gyroscope, accelerometer, sensor-fusion

I'm using *STM32F4* mcu with *MPU6050* on it. I want to get very accurate *yaw* angle using gyroscope with *Madgwick* filter. I tried lots of things: with and without gyro thresholds, with and without acceletometer, with and without other gyro axes. I also tried all gyro sensitivities, but nothing of this help. So about the problem - When I move and rotate controller from specific place and get it back after few seconds - yaw angle doesn't come back to zero:
(Start placement with yaw==0)
[image]
(In this picture yaw is also zero, but you can see, that *pcb* is not on the original place)
[image]

The *Madgwick* filter:

```c
void MadgwickAHRSupdateIMU(float gx, float gy, float gz, float ax, float ay, float az) {
    float recipNorm;
    float recipNormAccel;
    float recipNormS;
    float s0, s1, s2, s3;
    float s0_view, s1_view, s2_view, s3_view;
    float qDot1, qDot2, qDot3, qDot4;
    float _2q0, _2q1, _2q2, _2q3, _4q0, _4q1, _4q2 ,_8q1, _8q2, q0q0, q1q1, q2q2, q3q3;

    // Rate of change of quaternion from gyroscope
    qDot1 = 0.5f * (-q1 * gx - q2 * gy - q3 * gz);
    qDot2 = 0.5f * (q0 * gx + q2 * gz - q3 * gy);
    qDot3 = 0.5f * (q0 * gy - q1 * gz + q3 * gx);
    qDot4 = 0.5f * (q0 * gz + q1 * gy - q2 * gx);

    // Compute feedback only if accelerometer measurement valid (avoids NaN in accelerometer normalisation)
    if(!((ax == 0.0f) && (ay == 0.0f) && (az == 0.0f))) {

        // Normalise accelerometer measurement
        recipNormAccel = invSqrt(ax * ax + ay * ay + az * az);
        ax *= recipNormAccel;
        ay *= recipNormAccel;
        az *= recipNormAccel;

        // Auxiliary variables to avoid repeated arithmetic
        _2q0 = 2.0f * q0;
        _2q1 = 2.0f * q1;
        _2q2 = 2.0f * q2;
        _2q3 = 2.0f * q3;
        _4q0 = 4.0f * q0;
        _4q1 = 4.0f * q1;
        _4q2 = 4.0f * q2;
        _8q1 = 8.0f * q1;
        _8q2 = 8.0f * q2;
        q0q0 = q0 * q0;
        q1q1 = q1 * q1;
        q2q2 = q2 * q2;
        q3q3 = q3 * q3;

        // Gradient decent algorithm corrective step
        s0_view = _4q0 * q2q2 + _2q2 * ax + _4q0 * q1q1 - _2q1 * ay;
        s1_view = _4q1 * q3q3 - _2q3 * ax + 4.0f * q0q0 * q1 - _2q0 * ay - _4q1 + _8q1 * q1q1 + _8q1 * q2q2 + _4q1 * az;
        s2_view = 4.0f * q0q0 * q2 + _2q0 * ax + _4q2 * q3q3 - _2q3 * ay - _4q2 + _8q2 * q1q1 + _8q2 * q2q2 + _4q2 * az;
        s3_view = 4.0f * q1q1 * q3 - _2q1 * ax + 4.0f * q2q2 * q3 - _2q2 * ay;
        recipNormS = invSqrt(s0_view * s0_view + s1_view * s1_view + s2_view * s2_view + s3_view * s3_view); // normalise step magnitude
        s0 = s0_view * recipNormS;
        s1 = s1_view * recipNormS;
        s2 = s2_view * recipNormS;
        s3 = s3_view * recipNormS;

        // Apply feedback step
        qDot1 -= beta * s0;
        qDot2 -= beta * s1;
        qDot3 -= beta * s2;
        qDot4 -= beta * s3;
    }

    // Integrate rate of change of quaternion to yield quaternion
    q0 += qDot1 * (1.0f / sampleFreq);
    q1 += qDot2 * (1.0f / sampleFreq);
    q2 += qDot3 * (1.0f / sampleFreq);
    q3 += qDot4 * (1.0f / sampleFreq);

    // Normalise quaternion
    recipNorm = invSqrt(q0 * q0 + q1 * q1 + q2 * q2 + q3 * q3);
    q0 *= recipNorm;
    q1 *= recipNorm;
    q2 *= recipNorm;
    q3 *= recipNorm;
}

float invSqrt(float x) {
    if (x != 0)
        return 1.0f / sqrtf(x);
    return 1;
}
```

This is how I use the filter:

```c
#define GYRO_Y_THRESH 0.0045

void Process_IMU()
{
    //read raw data
    uint8_t data[14];
    uint8_t reg = ACCEL_XOUT_H;
    uint8_t mpu_address = MPU6050_ADDRESS_DEFAULT;


    while(HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(_MPU6050_I2C,(uint16_t)mpu_address,&reg,1,1000) != HAL_OK);
    while(HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(_MPU6050_I2C, (uint16_t)mpu_address, data, 14, 1000) != HAL_OK);

    /*-------- Accel ---------*/
    Accel_x = (int16_t)((int16_t)( data[0] << 8 ) | data[1]);
    Accel_y = (int16_t)((int16_t)( data[2] << 8 ) | data[3]);
    Accel_z = (int16_t)((int16_t)( data[4] << 8 ) | data[5]);

    /*-------- Gyrometer --------*/
    Gyro_x = (int16_t)((int16_t)( data[8] << 8  ) | data[9]);
    Gyro_y = (int16_t)((int16_t)( data[10] << 8 ) | data[11]);
    Gyro_z = (int16_t)((int16_t)( data[12] << 8 ) | data[13]);

    Accel_X = (float)((int32_t)Accel_x - Accel_x_bias)/(float)accel_sensitivity;
    Accel_Y = (float)((int32_t)Accel_y - Accel_y_bias)/(float)accel_sensitivity;
    Accel_Z = (float)((int32_t)Accel_z - Accel_z_bias)/(float)accel_sensitivity;

    Gyro_X =  (float)(((int32_t)Gyro_x - Gyro_x_bias)/(float)gyro_sensitivity)*M_PI/180.0 * STUPID_PRES;
    Gyro_Y =  (float)(((int32_t)Gyro_y - Gyro_y_bias)/(float)gyro_sensitivity)*M_PI/180.0 * STUPID_PRES;
    Gyro_Z =  (float)(((int32_t)Gyro_z - Gyro_z_bias)/(float)gyro_sensitivity)*M_PI/180.0 * STUPID_PRES;

    if (fabs(Gyro_Y ) < GYRO_Y_THRESH)
        Gyro_Y = 0;

    MadgwickAHRSupdateIMU(0,0,-Gyro_Y ,0,0,-accel_sensitivity);

}
```

(I don't want to use accelerometer values, because when I use them *yaw* angle starts changing when I move *pcb* without rotating it. And also *roll* and *pitch* start increasing even if I do not rotate *pcb* in these axes)
Now I use *ACCEL_FS_4* sensitivity for acceletometer and *GYRO_FS_2000* for gyro.

I also calibrate gyro and accelerometer at the begin.

What should I do to prevent this? I want yaw angle to come back to zero after some rotations.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The down vector is fixed because gravity always points down, and you can measure accelerations (gravity) with the accelerometers.

You can't fix heading without a magnetometer at least, to measure magnetic North, and even with a magnetometer you can have issues with nearby ferrous objects, electric fields, etc.

But with no magnetometer you can't fix your yaw (heading!) angle. Remember your gyroscopes are measuring angular *velocity*, not angular *position*, so your yaw (heading!) angle will drift with gyro bias.

Comment: But anyway it's quite strange, because deviation is always with negative sign and about 1.5^. I can't use magnetometer, because there are too many metal things around the pcb. "yaw (heading!) angle will drift with gyro bias." what does it mean, I calibrate gyro and accel, so I have biases for them?

Comment: @crackanddie - You can average the sensor readings while it's known to be stationary to determine the biases, but unfortunate "bias stability" is an issue - just like the name sounds, the bias isn't constant, so you still wind up with long-term drift.